# Setting Environment Variable from Eclipse vs. System

Tags: java, environment-variables, gurobi

I am using the Gurobi Optimizer, for which I need to set two environment variables: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `GRB_LICENSE_FILE`.

If I set the variables using Eclipse (Run As --> Run Configuration --> Environment), everything works correctly. If I set the variables through the system (using `export` in Linux), I get the error

```
no GurobiJni46 in java.library.path
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix this?

In the end, I want to run a web application in Tomcat, which would require those variables set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where you have set the environment variable using export are you then running your application from inside Eclipse or are you running your application from the command line?
The launcher for Eclipse usually explicitly sets the path using the command line switch `-Djava.library.path` which would overwrite what you have set in the environment.

If you set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running Tomcat it would work, provided that Tomcat doesn't override it in one of its start-up scripts!

Comment: What I was missing is that the issue here has to do with where the environment variable is set. It has to be set in the shell from which eclipse (or java, if not running through eclipse) is run.

Comment: Hi myahya, I am facing the same issue. So, where can we set our environment variables such that we don't need to set it in Eclipse explicitly ?